# Работа с Install Shield

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Что нужно сделать, чтобы моя программа, работающая с базами данных (`dbf`), работала и на другом компьютере? При копировании программы на другой комп она выдает ошибку. Я так понимаю, что там не хватает чего-то, а что конкретно, не знаю. Пробовал сделать через `install shield`, ничего не получилось. 
Выдает такую ошибку "Access violation at address 00495005 in module Project1.exe read of address 000002F4"

Answer (score 1):

Ну а написать ошибку вера не позволяет?
Могу предположить, что на том компьютере не стоит `BDE`.

Answer (score 0):

Я когда работал с базами данных, из папки `BDE` основные библиотеку закидывал в саму папку с программой, установки БД не требовалось, работало стабильно (даже на 2000).

Answer (score 0):

Если используете BDE, попробуйте "приготовить" его так, как я рекомендовал [**здесь**](http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/answer.asp?IDAnswer=27022).